# Hydraulic disc brakes stuck on new bike

Tags: brakes

I pulled the lever on a brand new hydraulic disc brake and the brake won't release.  What's up ?  The wheel was never removed and a brand new bike.

Comment: Since the bike is new the best thing to do is to take it back to the dealer. He has to fix the problem. If you bought it online you may be in greater trouble since you may have to send it back.

Comment: Exercise your warranty rights as a consumer.

Comment: What make and model of the brake? And what were you doing with the bike at the time?

Answer (score -1):

Are you able to remove the wheel? Once the wheel is removed amd the pads are no longer obstructed by the brake rotor, you need to insert a flat-bladed screwdriver between the pads and twist it to push the pads apart. If this works, then you should be able to put the wheel back in, fitting the rotor into the brake caliper. With everything back in place, try pulling the brake lever again to see if it works properly now.

If this doesn't work, then you probably have a more complicated issue that we would need more information to diagnose.

Comment: Must people will only manage to destroy their brake pads when they try this. Don't use a hard sharp tool, and take out pads first.

Comment: If they're incapable of doing this without destroying the pads, then they should just take it to a shop. That way they can pay for a bike mechanic to shove a screwdriver between their brake pads instead.